# IoC container - singleton or passed around instance?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, design-patterns, ioc-container

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to create a singleton to access unity container or pass it through the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386487/is-it-better-to-create-a-singleton-to-access-unity-container-or-pass-it-through-t)

I am introducing IoC container into the system. The natural question is, should it be a singleton or an instance passed to a class to use? I lean towards having it as a singleton instance because:

1. No need to clutter class definition like constructors, additional properties.
2. Clearer - one instance per application, one initialization routing.
3. Ability to have default mapping with overrides if necessary (like for unit testing).

Here is how it looks:

```
class Main
{
  public static void main(params string[] args)
  {
     IoCContaner.Intance.Add<IBar>();
     IoCContaner.Intance.Add<IBaz>();
     IoCContaner.Intance.Add<IQux>();

     var foo = new Foo();
     Foo.DoBarStuff();
  }
}

class Bar : IBar 
{ 
  public Bar(IBaz, IQuz) {} 
  public void DoBazStuff() { _baz.DoStuff(); }
}

class Foo
{
  public void DoBarStuff()
  {
     var bar = IoCContaner.Intance.Resolve<IBar>();
     bar.DoBazStuff();
  }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing and instead I should actually have something like:

```
class Foo
{
  IoCContainer _c;
  public Foo(IoCContainer c) { _c = c; }
  ...
  private void DoBarStuff()
  {
     var bar = _c.Resolve<IBar>();
     bar.DoBazStuff();
  }
}
```

Of course with the second approach I may always to fall back to the first one by passing around a singleton container instance.

EDITED: updated code examples

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386487/is-it-better-to-create-a-singleton-to-access-unity-container-or-pass-it-through-t

Comment: Voted myself to close as dup. Besides the only answer is diverged the attention from IoC usage to DI, which is not the thing I am asking about. Please vote to close.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Neither: both of those approaches hide your dependencies and make your classes hard to use. Instead, `Foo` should require an `IBar` in its constructor:

```
class Foo {
    private bar;
    public Foo(IBar bar) { this.bar = bar; }
    private void DoBarStuff() {
        this.bar.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

The only things that should know about your container are your application entry points.

See [Dependency Injection Myth: Reference Passing](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/10/21/dependency-injection-myth-reference-passing/) and [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) for additional in-depth discussion.

Comment: Boom. The only correct answer.

Comment: What if some particular condition within Foo is required to create your Bar, such that you can't instantiate your Bar before creating Foo, but instead need to pass a Type to it.

Comment: @Sparkie - in those cases, you usually require an `IBarFactory` and defer creation until you have enough information to create a `Bar` instance.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't want to deal with passing things around. That's why I want IoC container. It will wire classes up for me, no matter how many dependencies exist. That's its purpose and I don't think you are getting the sense of it.

Comment: @to all: I am sorry but that's not acceptable answer for me because having IFoo, IBar, IBaz, and 10 more interfaces with corresponding implementation that depend on each other, setting all this up is tedious and error prone. That's what IoC container is for. Jeff is welcome to do it manually but I'd rather rely on IoC container rather than on developers.

Comment: BTW, who are those guys who you give references to?

Comment: @Jeff: "@Sparkie - in those cases, you usually require an IBarFactory" that's exactly what IoC container is, which I dare to say you don't get the understanding of... People, please read the question and stop bumping up this answer.

Comment: @Schultz - sorry I wasn't clear. I wasn't saying you shouldn't use a container, just that you should only use it at the top of your object graph.

Comment: I'm going to answer. "Neither" also, static class with static members will suffice for a Wrapper around your IoC container.

Comment: @Phill: that's what IoCContaner.Intance is for, don't you think?

Comment: @Schultz9999 /facepalm forget it. http://www.manning.com/seemann/