# Creating new instances while still using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

### A quick description of the environment:

I have a class that represents a chatroom and has a dependency on a logger. It's not the same as a system-wide logger with cross-cutting concerns, but a logger that's tied to that specific chatroom. It logs all activity in that chatroom to it's unique log file. When the chatroom is created I want to open the log file, and when it's destroyed I want to close the log file.

### The Problem

Here's the relevant code I'm using.

```
public interface IChatroomLogger
{
    void Log(ServerPacket packet);
    void Open();
    void Close();
}

public class ChatroomLogger : IChatroomLogger
{
    // chatroom name will be used as a file name
    public ChatroomLogger(string chatroomName) { ... }
    public void Log(ServerPacket packet) { ... }
}

public class Chatroom
{
    public Chatroom(string name, IChatroomLogger logger)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.logger.Open();
    }

    public IChatromLogger Logger { get { return this.logger; } }
}

public interface IChatManager
{
    Chatroom Get(chatroomName);
}
```

It's used in the application like this:

```
var room = ChatManager.Get(chatroomName);
romm.DoStuff();
room.Logger.LogPacket(receivedPacket);
```

The `ChatManager` is a class which holds references to all chatrooms and is responsible for creating and removing them. I haven't written it yet but that's the interface I've been coding against.

### The Question

How do I get `ChatManager` to create new instances of `Chatroom` and still use dependency injection??

I'm using Unity to do all my other DI stuff. So far it's worked great. But I'm not sure how to work around this conundrum.

When my concrete implementation of `ChatManager` creates new chatrooms, it has to pass in an `IChatroomLogger`. It doesn't know how to construct that...but Unity does. But then I have to pass in `IUnityContainer` into the `ChatManager`.

```
public class ChatManager : IChatManager
{
    public ChatManager(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public Chat Get(string chatroomName)
    {
        // get logger from Unity somehow. Not sure how I'd 
        // pass chatroomName to the concrete instance
        var logger = ...
        return new Chatroom(chatroomName, logger);
    }
}
```

That just seems wrong for some reason. It seems cleaner to not have the domain know anything about what DI container I'm using.

How could I get new instances of class `Chatroom` while my application in the middle of running without resorting to some sort of service locator design? Am I overthinking it? Is it not a big deal to pass around Unity? Any thoughts are welcome!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-via-a-di-container/1945023#1945023

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386487/is-it-better-to-create-a-singleton-to-access-unity-container-or-pass-it-through-t

Comment: @Mark Seemann - you're everywhere! Seriously, how much sage advice could you possibly have? You're just one man! :). Thinking I may pre-order that book of yours...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. Using the IUnityContainer like this is no longer using Dependency Injection. Instead it's using the "Service Locator" pattern. What I usually do in cases like this is create an `IFactory<T>` interface, like this:

```
public IFactory<T>
{
    T Get();
}
```

Then implement the interface with a class that *does* know about and use the `IUnityContainer`. Set up your bindings so that `IFactory<>` requests will create an instance of this factory class. That way, you can inject the `IFactory<Logger>` interface into your `ChatManager`, and call `.Get()` any time you want a logger instance.

Comment: Excellent idea! I really like the simplicity of it. One question though - I need to pass my concrete logger a string (chatroomname) in it's constructor. Can you think of a good way to do that?

Comment: @Onisemus: In that case, you will probably want a more specialized factory interface (`ILoggerFactory`) that takes the name as a parameter for its `Get` method. The factory implementation should reside in the same package as your DI bindings, and use whatever mechanism Unity provides for passing that parameter along as a DI parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I also think you should avoid passing the container around.

- Add a IChatroomProvider to your design with a Create(string roomname) method
- In ChatroomProvider, use the container to create named instances (the container will manage the lifecyle of each named instance for you so you don't need to manage a dictionary).
- Register the ChatroomProvider with the container
- Let ChatManager take a dependency on IChatroomProvider
- When ChatManager needs a chatroom it can just ask its IChatroomProvider
- Use the container to create the ChatManager instance
- Logger instances will be created when chatrooms are created