# c# Unity Multiple Instantiation Using Resolve Refactoring

Tags: c#, unity-container

In my app I am using Unity container(through ServiceLocator) with constructor injection.

I have following class structure:

```
class Main
{

    void Main()
    {

        var c = ServiceLocator.Container.Resolve<C>(new ParameterOverrides { { "somedate", somedate } }, new ParameterOverrides { { "someRates", someRates } });
        var b = ServiceLocator.Container.Resolve<B>(new ParameterOverrides { { "c", c } }, new ParameterOverrides { { "somePara", somePara } });

    }
}

class A
{
    private B _b;

    public A(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}

class B
{
    private C _c;

    public B(C c, string somePara)
    {
        _c = c;
    }

}

class C
{

    public C(DateTime somedate, IDictionary<string, double> someRates)
    {

    }
}
```

Now you can see I have to call Resolve method and pass ParameterOverrides.
When the parameters and Resolve calls increases the main method becomes messy, like if C also expects some other class instances or parameters and so on. Please suggest best practices to refactor this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is not constructor injection, it's actually a common [anti-pattern](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container). For starters, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308424/unitycontainer-resolve-or-servicelocator-getinstance

Comment: It's constructor injection for class B, C. I am not using ServiceLocator inside class B, C I am injecting the dependency through constructor.

Comment: Constructor injection means, in your example, a constructor that looks like this "void Main(C c, B c)". The "clue" that it's the anti-pattern is that there is a dependency on the service locator inside of the class. You're using a ServiceLocator for sure, but it's not via constructor injection. Phrased differently, you're creating values "inside" the constructor instead of passing them "to" the constructor. Incidentally, I'd offer an answer but I am not familiar enough with the features of Unity's ServiceLocator for constructor injection.

Comment: Main class is the entry point of the app, I can't pass instances of object to Main class if it's a console app, Please look the code sample from perspective of class B & C and not from Main class perspective.  What I am looking for is avoid the messiness of too many resolves in Main class.

Comment: Understood. Cannot contribute a direct answer due to ignorance of Unity. What I'd like to express however is that other dependency injection systems allow this type of setup external to the class consuming it. E.g. AutoFac, Ninject, etc.

Comment: Thanks! if you are so interested in making that code sample using constructor injection please suggest how would you pass instances in void Main(C c, B c) in a console app which is executed as an exe. Please answer from unity container's perspective, since that what I can use in my proj.