# Ioc/DI - How to use the registered dependencies?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I think I'm missing a key part of how to actually use IoC/DI. I happen to be using the Unity container. I know how to setup a class to have it's dependencies injected and I also know how to make Unity register a type.

But what I don't know is how to actually then make use of these registrations.

So for example:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRepository, XmlRepository>();

var service = new MyService(container.Resolve<IRepository>());

public interface IRepository
{
    void GetStuff();
}

public class XmlRepository : IRepository
{
    public void GetStuff()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    private readonly IRepository _myRepository;
    public MyService(IRepository repository)
    {
        _myRepository = repository;
    }
}
```

Here I have a service layer which accepts a parameter of type `IRepository`. It's the *container* part that I seem to not be understanding.

- Isn't the point of IoC/DI to be able to not have to manually resolve types every time I need to create an instance? In my code I'm getting the container to resolve a type, unless I'm misunderstanding how this is supposed to work, isn't the container supposed to somehow automatically (with reflection?) inject the dependency I told it to use when I registered the type? `var service = new MyService(...)` Is calling `container.Resolve` the correct way of doing this?
- I've created a container, but how do I share this container amongst my project/code? This sort of relates to the first question. I had previously thought that there was a single place that you register types. So far the only way I can see how to get around this is to:

  - Keep registering types wherever I use them and end up with duplicated code
  - Pass the container around to every place I'm going to be resolving types
  - Neither of these ways are how I'd expect this to work

Comment: If IoC is correctly setup, the *only* service that must be manually resolved is the 'root' (there may be several). In this case the root is MyService, not IRespository. Thus, after registering MyService and IRepository, `var service = container.Resolve<MyService>();` - and the IoC container will automatically resolve the IRepository dependency. (Unity also auto-resolves non-registered concrete types, so don't even need to register MyService.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9501604/126014

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2386487/126014

Comment: Passing the container around to many places means that you want to use the container as a [service locator which is an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Isn't the point of IoC/DI to be able to not have to manually resolve types every time I need to create an instance?

No, that's the point of a *DI Container*, but there are drawbacks to using a container as well. Favour [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) over using a DI Container, as this will teach you how to use Dependency Injection using only first principles.

> I've created a container, but how do I share this container amongst my project/code?

You don't. The DI Container should only be used in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot) (if you use a DI Container at all).

Comment: This is a great answer, the Composition Root idea was a key idea I've been missing while learning this.

Answer (score 1):

Put your container setup in a module that runs when your program starts. You can call it from `Main`, for example. This is called a boot strapper.

See [Dependency Injection with Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx) for a good example of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `new MyService(container.Resolve<IRepository>())`. To get an instance of `MyService`, just use `container.Resolve<MyService>()`; it will automatically resolves the dependencies for `MyService`.