# Structuremap - how can I get a named instance and pass parameter at runtime?

Tags: c#, structuremap

I can add a named instance to structuremap like this:

```
For<IFoo>().Add<Foo>().Named("FooOne");
```

which I can then get with:

```
ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IFoo>("FooOne");
```

and I can pass parameters at runtime by registering like this:

```
For<IFoo>().Add<Foo>().Ctor<string>("someParam");
```

and get an instance like this:

```
ObjectFactory.With("someParam").EqualTo("blah").GetInstance<IFoo>();
```

All fine. But I want to have a named instance and pass it a parameter. So I'm registering like this:

```
For<IFoo>().Add<Foo>().Named("FooOne").Ctor<string>("someParam");
```

But I can't work out the syntax for getting a named instance AND passing it the parameter at runtime??
I'm trying to do something like:

```
ObjectFactory.With("someParam").EqualTo("blah").GetNamedInstance<IFoo>("FooOne");
```

But structuremap doesn't give me the option to GetNamedInstance after adding the parameter. Where am I going wrong?

Alternative approach suggestions would also be good. Essentially what I'm trying to do is register a concrete type for each element of an enum, and use the enum item to name it and retrieve it by name. But I need to be able to pass a parameter to the constructor at runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StructureMap doesn't provide an API for doing that.

You can use an abstract factory. There are lot's of examples that can be found here on Stack Overflow.

A few of them are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-via-a-di-container/1945023#1945023) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926826/cant-combine-factory-di).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var args = new ExplicitArguments();
args.SetArg("someParam", blah);
ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IFoo>(args, "FooOne");
```