# Structuremap configuration for choosing particular type by varying different constructor type

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am trying to choose different logger for different type of services. In my following class scenario, i want to use DbAppender for a service which need to log to db and FileAppender for a service which need to log to file.

Here is the class design i have:

```
public interface ILogger
{

}
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly IAppender _appender;

    public Logger(IAppender appender)
    {
        _appender = appender;
    }
}
public interface IAppender
{

}

public interface IRepository
{

}
public class DbAppender : IAppender
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    public DbAppender(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}

public class FileAppender : IAppender
{

}

public interface IHelloDbService
{

}
public class HelloServiceWithDbLog : IHelloDbService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public HelloServiceWithDbLog(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public interface IHelloFileService
{

}
public class HelloServiceWithFileLog : IHelloFileService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public HelloServiceWithFileLog(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Now i have to configure structureMap dependency injection accordingly so that for DbService it has to choose logger with db capability and for FileService, it has to choose logger with file capability.

```
    // this has to configure to choose Logger with FileAppender.
    x.For<IHelloFileService>().Use<HelloServiceWithFileLog>();
                .Ctor<ILogger>().Is<Logger>();

    // this has to configure to choose logger passing DbAppender.
             x.For<IHelloDbService>().Use<HelloServiceWithDbLog>();
                .Ctor<ILogger>().Is<Logger>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no structure map expert, and there may be a way to use named instances in structure map but I think you could just create subclasses for the type of logging that you want to do and inject those subclasses into the constructors:

```
public class DbLogger : Logger
{
    public DbLogger (DbAppender appender) : base(appender)
    {        
    }
}


x.For<IHelloDbService>().Use<HelloServiceWithDbLog>();
                .Ctor<ILogger>().Is<DbLogger>();
```

after some research it seems that structure map might provide what you want, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380933/structuremap-how-can-i-get-a-named-instance-and-pass-parameter-at-runtime) and [the docs](http://docs.structuremap.net/InstanceExpression.htm) and you could also achieve what you want by injecting an [abstract factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-via-a-di-container/1945023#1945023) to create the loggers rather than the loggers themselves.