# Dependency Injection and the Strategy Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, strategy-pattern

There is an enormous amount of discussion on this topic, but everyone seems to miss an obvious answer.    I'd like help vetting this "obvious" IOC container solution.  The various conversations assume run-time selection of strategies and the use of an IOC container.  I will continue with these assumptions.

I also want to add the assumption that it is not a single strategy that must be selected.  Rather, I might need to retrieve an object-graph that has several strategies found throughout the nodes of the graph.

I will first quickly outline the two commonly proposed solutions, and then I will present the "obvious" alternative that I'd like to see an IOC container support.  I will be using Unity as the example syntax, though my question is not specific to Unity.

#### Named Bindings

This approach requires that every new strategy has a binding manually added:

```
Container.RegisterType<IDataAccess, DefaultAccessor>();
Container.RegisterType<IDataAccess, AlphaAccessor>("Alpha");
Container.RegisterType<IDataAccess, BetaAccessor>("Beta");
```

...and then the correct strategy is explicitly requested:

```
var strategy = Container.Resolve<IDataAccess>("Alpha");
```

- Pros: Simple, and supported by all IOC Containers
- Cons:

  - Typically binds the caller to the IOC Container, and certainly requires the caller to know something about the strategy (such as the name "Alpha").
  - Every new strategy must be manually added to the list of bindings.
  - This approach is not suitable for handling multiple strategies in an object graph.  In short, it does not meet requirements.

#### Abstract Factory

To illustrate this approach, assume the following classes:

```
public class DataAccessFactory{
    public IDataAccess Create(string strategy){
        return //insert appropriate creation logic here.
    }
    public IDataAccess Create(){
        return //Choose strategy through ambient context, such as thread-local-storage.
    }
}
public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(DataAccessFactory datafactory)
    {
        //variation #1. Not sufficient to meet requirements.
        var myDataStrategy = datafactory.Create("Alpha");
        //variation #2.  This is sufficient for requirements.
        var myDataStrategy = datafactory.Create();
    }
}
```

The IOC Container then has the following binding:

```
Container.RegisterType<DataAccessFactory>();
```

- Pros:

  - The IOC Container is hidden from consumers
  - The "ambient context" is closer to the desired result but...
- Cons:

  - The constructors of each strategy might have different needs.  But now the responsibility of constructor injection has been transferred to the abstract factory from the container. In other words, every time a new strategy is added it may be necessary to modify the corresponding abstract factory.
  - Heavy use of strategies means heavy amounts of creating abstract factories.  It would be nice if the IOC container simply gave a *little* more help.
  - If this is a multi-threaded application and the "ambient context" is indeed provided by thread-local-storage, then by the time an object is using an injected abstract-factory to create the type it needs, it may be operating on a different thread which no longer has access to the necessary thread-local-storage value.

#### Type Switching / Dynamic Binding

This is the approach that I want to use instead of the above two approaches.  It involves providing a delegate as part of the IOC container binding.  Most all IOC Containers already have this ability, but this specific approach has an important subtle difference.

The syntax would be something like this:

```
Container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataAccess),
    new InjectionStrategy((c) =>
    {
        //Access ambient context (perhaps thread-local-storage) to determine
        //the type of the strategy...
        Type selectedStrategy = ...;
        return selectedStrategy;
    })
);
```

Notice that the `InjectionStrategy` is *not* returning an instance of `IDataAccess`.  Instead it is returning a type description that implements `IDataAccess`.  The IOC Container would then perform the usual creation and "build up" of that type, which might include other strategies being selected.

This is in contrast to the standard type-to-delegate binding which, in the case of Unity, is coded like this:

```
Container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataAccess),
    new InjectionFactory((c) =>
    {
        //Access ambient context (perhaps thread-local-storage) to determine
        //the type of the strategy...
        IDataAccess instanceOfSelectedStrategy = ...;
        return instanceOfSelectedStrategy;
    })
);
```

The above actually comes close to satisfying the overall need, but definitely falls short of the hypothetical Unity `InjectionStrategy`.

Focusing on the first sample (which used a hypothetical Unity `InjectionStrategy`):

- Pros:

  - Hides the container
  - No need either to create endless abstract factories, or have consumers fiddle with them.
  - No need to manually adjust IOC container bindings whenever a new strategy is available.
  - Allows the container to retain lifetime management controls.
  - Supports a pure DI story, which means that a multi-threaded app can create the entire object-graph on a thread with the proper thread-local-storage settings.
- Cons:

  - Because the `Type` returned by the strategy was not available when the initial IOC container bindings were created, it means there may be a tiny performance hit the first time that type is returned.  In other words, the container must on-the-spot reflect the type to discover what constructors it has, so that it knows how to inject it.  All subsequent occurrences of that type should be fast, because the container can cache the results it found from the first time.  This is hardly a "con" worth mentioning, but I'm trying for full-disclosure.
  - ???

Is there an existing IOC container that can behave this way?  Anyone have a Unity custom injection class that achieves this effect?

Comment: how is your example for `Type Switching / Dynamic Binding` realistically different than `Abstract Factory`?  

You would end up having to write almost identical code for both.  It's just that one is a bunch of classes, and the other is a bunch of  `Container.RegisterType` calls for each type.

Answer (score 21):

As far as I can tell, this question is about run-time selection or mapping of one of several candidate Strategies.

There's no reason to rely on a DI Container to do this, as there are at least three ways to do this in a container-agnostic way:

- Use a [Metadata Role Hint](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/09/MetadataRoleHint)
- Use a [Role Interface Role Hint](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/10/RoleInterfaceRoleHint)
- Use a [Partial Type Name Role Hint](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/11/PartialTypeNameRoleHint)

My personal preference is the Partial Type Name Role Hint.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Is it considered "bad taste" to generate `factories` which are not directly related to initial binding process? Apart from it: is factory in question not injected to `Customer` constructor? That assumes there also will be no `Customers` on system start, then.. Is use of `new` prohibited in IoC-container-wired system?

Comment: @jungle_mole Abstract Factory is also an option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1945023/126014

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this requirement in many forms over the last couple of years. Firstly let's pull the main points I can see in your post

> assume run-time selection of strategies and the use of an IOC container ... add the assumption that it is not a single strategy that must be selected. Rather, I might need to retrieve an object-graph that has several strategies ... [must not] binds the caller to the IOC Container ... Every new strategy must [not need to] be manually added to the list of bindings ...  It would be nice if the IOC container simply gave a little more help.

I have used [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.org) as my container of choice for some time now and one of the drivers for this decision is that it has extensive support for generics. It is through this feature that we will implement your requirements.

I'm a firm believer that the code should speak for itself so I'll jump right in ...

- I have defined an extra class `ContainerResolvedClass<T>` to demonstrate that Simple Injector finds the right implementation(s) and successfully injects them into a constructor. That is the only reason for the class `ContainerResolvedClass<T>`. (This class exposes the handlers that are injected into it for test purposes via `result.Handlers`.)

This first test requires that we get one implementation back for the fictional class `Type1`:

```
[Test]
public void CompositeHandlerForType1_Resolves_WithAlphaHandler()
{
    var container = this.ContainerFactory();

    var result = container.GetInstance<ContainerResolvedClass<Type1>>();
    var handlers = result.Handlers.Select(x => x.GetType());

    Assert.That(handlers.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(handlers.Contains(typeof(AlphaHandler<Type1>)), Is.True);
}
```

This second test requires that we get one implementation back for the fictional class `Type2`:

```
[Test]
public void CompositeHandlerForType2_Resolves_WithAlphaHandler()
{
    var container = this.ContainerFactory();

    var result = container.GetInstance<ContainerResolvedClass<Type2>>();
    var handlers = result.Handlers.Select(x => x.GetType());

    Assert.That(handlers.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(handlers.Contains(typeof(BetaHandler<Type2>)), Is.True);
}
```

This third test requires that we get two implementations back for the fictional class `Type3`:

```
[Test]
public void CompositeHandlerForType3_Resolves_WithAlphaAndBetaHandlers()
{
    var container = this.ContainerFactory();

    var result = container.GetInstance<ContainerResolvedClass<Type3>>();
    var handlers = result.Handlers.Select(x => x.GetType());

    Assert.That(handlers.Count(), Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(handlers.Contains(typeof(AlphaHandler<Type3>)), Is.True);
    Assert.That(handlers.Contains(typeof(BetaHandler<Type3>)), Is.True);
}
```

These tests seems to meet your requirements and best of all *no containers are harmed in the solution*.

---

The trick is to use a combination of parameter objects and marker interfaces. The parameter objects contain the data for the behaviour (i.e. the `IHandler`'s) and the marker interfaces govern which behaviours act on which parameter objects.

Here are the marker interfaces and parameter objects - you'll note that `Type3` is marked with both marker interfaces:

```
private interface IAlpha { }
private interface IBeta { }

private class Type1 : IAlpha { }
private class Type2 : IBeta { }
private class Type3 : IAlpha, IBeta { }
```

Here are the behaviours (`IHandler<T>`'s):

```
private interface IHandler<T> { }

private class AlphaHandler<TAlpha> : IHandler<TAlpha> where TAlpha : IAlpha { }
private class BetaHandler<TBeta> : IHandler<TBeta> where TBeta : IBeta { }
```

This is the single method that will find all implementations of an open generic:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> GetLoadedOpenGenericImplementations(Type type)
{
    var types =
        from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        from t in assembly.GetTypes()
        where !t.IsAbstract
        from i in t.GetInterfaces()
        where i.IsGenericType
        where i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type
        select t;

    return types;
}
```

And this is the code that configures the container for our tests:

```
private Container ContainerFactory()
{
    var container = new Container();

    var types = this.GetLoadedOpenGenericImplementations(typeof(IHandler<>));

    container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(IHandler<>), types);

    container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
        typeof(ContainerResolvedClass<>),
        typeof(ContainerResolvedClass<>));

    return container;
}
```

And finally, the test class `ContainerResolvedClass<>`

```
private class ContainerResolvedClass<T>
{
    public readonly IEnumerable<IHandler<T>> Handlers;

    public ContainerResolvedClass(IEnumerable<IHandler<T>> handlers)
    {
        this.Handlers = handlers;
    }
}
```

I realise this post is a quite long, but I hope it clearly demonstrates a possible solution to your problem ...

Comment: Fantastic work, and greatly appreciated.  However, as is, two issues prevent this from being my answer.  First, what if I add a second constructor parameter to ContainerResolvedClass, and that second parameter represents a different kind of "strategy"?  Now I must modify the definition of ContainerResolvedClass.  Second, to resolve to a particular strategy(ies), I'm still effectively providing a (generic) parameter 'T' to Container.GetInstance(ContainerResolvedClass<T>).  Furthermore, this approach has a service-locator slant to it.  I'm looking for pure DI.  I will update my question params.

Comment: @BrentArias `Container.GetInstance` is test code. You only need to reference the container in the composition root. I've covered an example of 2 strategies with the `Type3` test where you get 2 behaviours for one type. I have not specifically coded this to suit the strategy pattern because it is equally applicable to the observer and visitor patterns. I've written this as a general example of code that will give you one or many implementations based purely on code/configuration without any of your classes referencing the container other than the composition root.

Comment: This code can return nothing just as Type Switching can and the way to mitigate it in either case is to have a singleton `NullHandler` to fall back on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response but maybe it will help others.

I have a pretty simple approach. I simply create a StrategyResolver to not be directly depending on Unity.

```
public class StrategyResolver : IStrategyResolver
{
    private IUnityContainer container;

    public StrategyResolver(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        this.container = unityContainer;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>(string namedStrategy)
    {
        return this.container.Resolve<T>(namedStrategy);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class SomeClass: ISomeInterface
{
    private IStrategyResolver strategyResolver;

    public SomeClass(IStrategyResolver stratResolver)
    {
        this.strategyResolver = stratResolver;
    }

    public void Process(SomeDto dto)
    {
        IActionHandler actionHanlder = this.strategyResolver.Resolve<IActionHandler>(dto.SomeProperty);
        actionHanlder.Handle(dto);
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
container.RegisterType<IActionHandler, ActionOne>("One");
container.RegisterType<IActionHandler, ActionTwo>("Two");
container.RegisterType<IStrategyResolver, StrategyResolver>();
container.RegisterType<ISomeInterface, SomeClass>();
```

Now, the nice thing about this is that I will never have to touch the StrategyResolver ever again when adding new strategies in the future.

It's very simple. Very clean and I kept the dependency on Unity to a strict minimum. The only time I would have touch the StrategyResolver is if I decide to change container technology which is very unlikely to happen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution makes use of service locator which is considered to be an anti-pattern due to arguments around user experience, solid and encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

I generally use a combination of your **Abstract Factory** and **Named Bindings** options.  After trying many different approaches, I find this approach to be a decent balance.

What I do is create a factory that essentially wraps the instance of the container.  See the section in Mark's [article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) called *Container-based Factory*.  As he suggests, I make this factory part of the composition root.

To make my code a little cleaner and less "magic string" based, I use an enum to denote the different possible strategies, and use the .ToString() method to register and resolve.

From your Cons of these approaches:

*Typically binds the caller to the IOC Container*

In this approach, the container is referenced in the factory, which is part of the Composition Root, so this is no longer an issue (in my opinion).

*. . . and certainly requires the caller to know something about the strategy (such as the
   name "Alpha").*

*Every new strategy must be manually added to the list
   of bindings. This approach is not suitable for handling multiple
   strategies in an object graph. In short, it does not meet
   requirements.*

At some point, code needs to be written to acknowledge the mapping between the structure that provides the implementation (container, provider, factory, etc.) and the code that requires it.  I don't think you can get around this unless you want to use something that is purely convention-based.

*The constructors of each strategy might have different needs. But now the responsibility of constructor injection has been transferred to the abstract factory from the container. In other words, every time a new strategy is added it may be necessary to modify the corresponding abstract factory.*

This approach solves this concern completely.

*Heavy use of strategies means heavy amounts of creating abstract factories.[...]*

Yes, you will need one abstract factory for each set of strategies.

*If this is a multi-threaded application and the "ambient context" is indeed provided by thread-local-storage, then by the time an object is using an injected abstract-factory to create the type it needs, it may be operating on a different thread which no longer has access to the necessary thread-local-storage value.*

This will no longer be an issue since TLC will not be used.

I don't feel that there is a perfect solution, but this approach has worked well for me.