# Autofac IoC - Should all the dependencies or types registered in the Application startup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I've started learning on how to use AutoFac IoC Container in ASP.Net MVC. All examples that I've seen so far, shows how to register components and services in the Application Auto_Start.

So that makes all my services & components registered as global ones, correct ? i.e., it will be applied for all incoming request.

1. Can someone show how I can use Dependency injector for functionalities that are just specific to one or few pages.
   E.g., A profanity checker or spell checker service JUST for my registration page - description field.
2. Can I create multiple ContainerBuilder and resolve just the types within that ?

To make my question more clear,
Each and every page will have page specific functionalities that I want to do using DI. Do I need to register my types in the Application startup i.e., globally ? Is DI is about registering all types & components globally ?

What would be the recommended way of registering types that are used in just a page? A sample code will help me a lot.

Comment: Related - resolving run-time dependencies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1945023/126014

Comment: Also related to resolving run-time dependencies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22705794/126014

Comment: Unless the profanity checker has to maintain state, and isn't thread-safe, you can register at start-up time and reuse the same, single object over and over again for hours and days. That's more efficient than creating it per-request.

Comment: For more information about efficient graph creation, see http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence

Comment: @MarkSeemann thanks for useful links - Knowing about the Abstract Factory was useful. My question is more on how ; Should I register my types globally or not ? If not can i create separate autofac DI container specific to that page ?  Does it increase the Resolving time for the DI Container ? Is is the right way ?

Comment: If the types are thread-safe, it'll be most efficient to register them as Singletons. You can read more about lifetime management in chapter 8 of [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I should close out this long pending questions. This is what I have observed :There won't be any major performance hit, as the objects are created /resolved when requested.